# css superfish menu, not lining up correctly

Tags: css, menu, superfish

I have been trying to work on a superfish navigation menu, with a little custom work, but for some reason things aren't working properly.

For some reason on fiddle the dropdown will not hide, though this works on a desktop.

the problem is during the hover state the drop down looks funny and will not drop down vertically but opens up horizontally.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WsuJw/)

```
<nav id="menu">

    <ul id="test">
    <li><a href="#">Test 1</a>

        <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Drop 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Drop 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Drop 1</a></li>
</ul>

    </li> 
    <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
        </ul>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

to your CSS, i added this and it shows/hides the dropdown accordingly. Add it to the bottom.

```
ul ul {display:none !important; }
ul li:hover ul{display:block !important; }
```

hope that works for you.

Edit: ok, check the fiddle. Its working as it should. You can apply CSS as needed.
http://jsfiddle.net/somdow/mH32X/

Edit 3: ok, check the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/somdow/mH32X/

this on a given width, hides the superfish menu and displays another menu to which you can construct the toggle that usually appears in mobile sites where they load from the sides etc.

you can either do it this way or, youd have to write some jQuery/Javascript. Something like.

Pseudo code:

```
var x = the screens width
if(screen.width < x ){
//go to the menus "nav" tag and remove the sf-menu class
}
```

which will do the same thing but i wouldnt recomend it because sf-menu is tied to ALL the animations and styling etc. Removing that class like that will remove EVERYTHING. youd have to write seperate CSS to support both menus which will turn into way more code. Id suggest sticking with the media queries.

Comment: not really.. this is the fiddle updated with some code http://jsfiddle.net/WsuJw/5/

what i want is for this to happen as the basic menu here.. 

http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/examples/

i wanted it to drop like this...


thank you for your help

Comment: check my updated answer. Overall i just kept the same structure and worked your menu into it. Id suggest, if your going to add your own css, do it at the bottom of the superfish css so it doesnt mess anything up. As far as the menu in the HTML goes, kee the same classes/ids that they have and work your menu into it.  Good luck

Comment: I was trying to avoid the sf-menu on the UL as a class so i could wrap it in a nav tag so I could make a mobile toggle ..

Comment: Ok, im confused, so what your saying is, you want to try and recreate the superfish menu effects in your own way so that you can then do something else with it on a mobile platform?

Comment: What I wanted to do is create the menu using superfish yes.... for the menu effects and drop down... and once it goes responsive it basically becomes a toggle element that we see..

Basically I wanted the UL and LI elements classless that is why in my original example i have <nav id-menu>

Comment: check this out ..  http://jsfiddle.net/6vp3U/

something like this... you see? what sucks about this one is... that when in responsive mode they use a little div for the arrow ... and only a portion of it is clickable.. where as a good responsive design the whole item would have the ability to be click... like this

http://themes.themeton.com/gravity/  <-- in responsive mode is exactly what i am trying to do